# Cannot uninstall Ubuntu... boot problems

Tags: boot, bios, ext4

I've been trying to remove Ubuntu from a laptop (separate issue), but I've not been able... any suggestions will be appreciated. Here some details:

- Dell Inspiron laptop, 32 bit, no UEFI secure boot
- Have Edubuntu (version of Ubuntu 12.04) installed
- Single Installation (does not have dual boot)
- If I try to boot using a windows installation CD, it simply does not, it starts reading from the CD, for about 30 seconds,and then boots Ubuntu.
- BIOS correctly set to boot from CD drive first. Hard drive formatted as ext4 Since I cannot get the CD started, I cannot get the MBR fixed, so I cannot use the fix above.

Could it be that Windows installer cannot see a "viable" hard drive to install since cannot work with ext4?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to wipe the hard drive?

Comment: did you try to boot with any other CD (e.g. ubuntu) just to see if the BIOS really boot from CD, also verify the Windows CD, it is not a problem having Ext4 formatted drive as Windows would see the space but would not recognize the Ext4 type code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows installation disks typically require you to "Press any key to boot from CD" before it fully boots. The fact that the CD loads for about 30 seconds makes it sound like for some reason you're supposed to be doing this but the message is not being displayed for some reason. **Try spamming the space bar when you hear the CD running.**

With regards to not being able to see the hard disk, what you're thinking would not be the case. Even though the *partiton* is formatted as ext4, Windows would still be able to see the physical disk.

So, if pressing the space bar doesn't work, you might want to check the disk you made in another computer, it could be defective.

Comment: Thanks. At the end was a defective img file of the windows install disk. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing windows from a usb stick instructions here.
[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)
to find the iso just google your windows version number iso.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article. This has similarities to your problem.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17903/remove-ubuntu-or-xp-from-the-windows-7-boot-menu/

Answer (score 0):

boot into ubuntu using CD choose "Try Ubuntu" connect to internet, open up a terminal window using alt-t then issue : boot-repair

if boot-repair is not found, then install it :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair &&
boot-repair

click Recommended Repair. Write on a paper the new URL that will appear. Reboot the pc, you should get a GRUB menu with access to both Ubuntu and Windows. If any problem, indicate the new URL.